# Is it possible to have C++11 code in a Python 2.7 module?

Tags: python-2.7, c++11, module, visual-c++-2008

I am writing a module in C++ that detects pitches from the microphone, which is going to be used in a FreePIE script. I have successfully compiled the module for Python 3, but FreePIE uses Python 2, so I need to compile it for Python 2. I noticed that the compiler I have to use (VC++ 2008) does not support C++11, but my program relies heavily on C++11 features. Is there a way to compile modules for Python 2 on Windows that uses C++11? I would really not like to go through my code fixing each source file and making it work with C++03.

Comment: Use a different compiler that supports both the language features and the ABI?

Comment: I found that it is possible to use MinGW to compile (I thought only VC++ 9 was compatible), so I'm going to try that.